# Sample weights scaling in sklearn.svm.SVC

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python, scikit-learn

It seems that for `sklearn.svm.SVC`, different scaling of `sample_weight` makes the classifier behaves differently. Is it correct? If yes, how does the `sample_weight` work?

```
sample_weights = np.ones((X.shape[0])) / X.shape[0]

from sklearn.svm import SVC

clf0 = SVC()
clf0.fit(X, y, sample_weights*10)
plt.subplot(121)
visualize_result(clf0, X, y)

clf1 = SVC()
clf1.fit(X, y, sample_weights*5)
plt.subplot(122)
visualize_result(clf1, X, y)
```

And the result is

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In SVC optimization problem, `C` parameter changes to `C[i]`, where i is index of sample. Each `C[i]` is `C[i] = C * sample_weight[i]`. AFAIK when you use sample_weights and class_weights simultaneously - `C[i] = C * sample_weight[i] * class_weight[class[i]]`

1. Official documentation of  scikit-learn [unbalanced problems](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#unbalanced-problems)
2. LibSVM manual [Unbalanced Data and Solving the Two-variable
   Sub-problem](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) page 26

Thus when you  providing less sample_weights - you classifier becomes more regularized.